# javadoc fail when using jdk12 to build language-level 9 javadoc

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, java-9, java-12

I'm using jdk 12 to build a maven project of language level 9.
The compile can succeed but it cannot generate javadoc correctly.

In short the error code is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.1.0:jar (default) on project commonx: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - The code being documented uses modules but the packages defined in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/ are in the unnamed module.
```

code is at https://github.com/XenoAmess/commonx/tree/3d875ee71ba1712b1b2bf76e89af08c5683fe57d

travis-ci is at https://travis-ci.org/XenoAmess/commonx/builds/540181778

I can do this with jdk9 or 10, but NO jdk 12 can I found which can build this javadoc right.
I tried zulu, oracle open jdk, adopt open jdk, amazon-corretto(11), all of them are the latest binary version I can get.

Win10 x64 I use but according to travis-ci's report it shall not be caused by system because I use linux x64 on travis.

If any guys can get it "maven install" using any jdk 12, please tell me what shall I do.

Thanks sincerely.

---

update: 2019/06/03

We change language level to 8.

Then it can build the javadoc correctly(on AdoptOpenJDK12)

Don't know why.

https://travis-ci.org/XenoAmess/commonx/builds/540461237

Well then.

We will stay on language level 8 before they fix the bug in OpenJDK.

(But some part of this library shall not be able to run on jre 8...well anyway.)

Comment: First I would suggest to use most recent versions of all plugins for JDK9+ (for example maven-compiler-plugin)...Why are you duplicating classes in your code instead of using them as dependencies (this will produce many issues for later users) etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise 1. I don't think maven-compiler-plugin have trouble here, the thing that cannot build is javadoc. 2.Please tell me what is "plugins for JDK9+",and why you think using "plugins for JDK9+" will help jdk12 build the javadoc. 3.The "duplicateing classes" are actually extended util classes, thus useful. Even not, it is irrelevant to the question I asked here.

Comment: When you compare the directory tree of JDK 11’s docs and those of JDK 9 or 10, you’ll notice that the structure has changed. I.e., there are now sub-directories for the modules. It seems that JDK 11+ javadoc always expects the new subdirectories for software using modules. Changing to language level 8 effectively disables modules. Since JDK 9 and 10 are supposed to be intermediate versions whose end-of-life has been reached already, it’s not clear whether a fix for targeting these versions can ever be expected.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE FOR THOSE WHO GOOGLED THIS BUG: 
If the project uses source/target 8, adding 8 in javadoc configuration should make the project build able on jdk {11, 12, 13}:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>8</source>
    </configuration>
     ...
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add following line in configuration of **maven-javadoc-plugin**

`<detectJavaApiLink>false</detectJavaApiLink>`